# using MVVM binding for composite fields

Tags: mvvm, model-binding

I have a quick (hopefully) question on how to implement a composite field using MVVM.

I have 2 examples, one is on the sql end I am storing gps coordinates in the following manner "Latitude,Longitude" for instance "45.55555,-80.00000".  the other example is storing feet and inches as a single double field with it being ft.in.

How should I go about this?  Should I have two fields and in the model or Viewmodel composite them if the other piece exists?  Should I bind them to the same field and somehow validate the sets?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Model I normally use a structure/layout that is closest/easiest to the source so it can be easily/quickly read and written.

In the ViewModel I aim for a representation of the View to accommodate the bindings.

In general I make the ViewModel responsible for the transformation between the Model and ViewModel.

So whether or not a property of the ViewModel and the Model should have one field or two depends on the requirements of the View and the Source.

Comment: So for example with my GPS field, it is one field in the sql table, I should have one field in the model and the view model should most likely have two, one for each entry and then both of those should be responsible for pushing back a correct collated field?  and the reverse is true, each property is also responsible for parsing out it's portion of the data?

Comment: I would make the ViewModel (not the properties) responsible for parsing/collating the Model's properties. BTW: the sql table doesn't sound very normalized to me...

Comment: No, it's not, but that is because we need a quite generic table that will hold data from up to 50 different entry forms.  For instance Alpha01 on one form might be project name and on another form might have first name.  From once that data has been transmitted back it'll be parsed back into a better structure.  But yes this is one large flatfile.

Comment: Ah, yes that can be a very valid reason. Have you considered XML as storage type?

Comment: Perhaps in the future, at this time time constraints are pushing to get the project working.